# The roof covering made of tar

Tags: word-request, verbs

In everyday speech (not technical), what do you call this **material / coverage** which is used to avoid leaking the roof when it rains and **what verb** do you usually use to describe what the workers are doing?
[image][image]

Comment: In this case, you want the *[covering](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/covering)*, not the *[coverage](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/coverage)*.

Comment: @A-friend Is there something you are not happy about with my answer? Just curious as I am trying to figure our if I left important things out. If you Google the terms I gave you such as "torch down" you will see they are standard terms. Lambie also provided some useful terms too.

Comment: One +1 for the great response! Sorry, for the mistaken pointing. Please just edit your post and let people could understand easily that the second image is about a material called "torch-down" and its respective action is called "torching down a roof". I have already signed your post as the answer to my question. Thank you very much @Eddie Kal. :)

Comment: @A-friend Thanks. Edited my answer. Great question by the way.

Comment: I.e. @Eddie Kal I need to know would it be correct to say: **We need to "torch-down the roof"** as soon as possible? Or **we need to buy 100 roles of torch-downs**.

Comment: Thank you very much @Eddie Kal for the follow-up and your concern. It would be great if you do me a favor and edit the post again and include the needed data to accomplish it. :)

Comment: @A-friend Answer revised. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: So @Eddie Kal, as you mentioned, **torch-down rubber** is the matterial name and we **"do/install torch-down roofing"** or just **to torch-down a roof**. Right? :)

Comment: @A-friend Yes and yes. However, although "torch-down rubber" is widely used and understood, whether it is accurate is where it gets tricky. Here you can find a [list of materials used in torch-down roofing](https://www.improvenet.com/r/costs-and-prices/torch-down-roofing) If you use non-_rubberoid_ (or _rubberized_) materials, namely materials that do not contain rubber, occasionally you might get the objection "Well, that ain't rubber."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flattening of the black rolls is called **laying down** whatever material they are using. In general this kind of roofing (laying down, unrolling, flattening, and adhering rolls) is known as doing a **flat roof**, as opposed to a [shingle roof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roof_shingle). There's more than one possibility of the actual material they use. One possible material used is called by some people "fiberglass liner". Lambie's answer provides a useful link to some other possible materials.

The second photo shows a roofer doing a **torch-down**. Torch-down refers to the process of heating up the rolls of material and adhering them to your roof. The whole thing is also called torch-down roofing, from laying down material to torch-heating the them. So you would say, "*Today we are doing/installing torch-down roofing.*" when referring to the roofing job from soup to nuts. Or you could say "*Have you begun the torch-down yet?*" referring to the single process of slowly unfurling a roll of material while torching it at one end to melt it and make it stick. [Here is an example on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvWRc9fAP7s).

Just so you know, there is another method that employs multiple layers of covering. I have seen **2-ply torch down rubber** applied to the roof where roofers anchored two layers of covering down and then used torch to fuse them together *after everything was rolled out, flattened out, and anchored down*. It is also called a torch-down.

When you use rubber, the material is call **torch down rubber**, but some people also call other materials "torch down rubber". It is more of a layman's term. So you could say "We need to buy 100 rolls of torch-down rubber."

p.s. I have seen two roofing jobs and was roped into helping out and pulling my weight.

Answer (score -2):

Question: In everyday speech (not technical), what do you call this material / coverage which is used to avoid leaking the roof when it rains and what verb do you usually use to describe what the workers are doing.

Answer: They are applying a (PVC or vinyl) covering to the roof.

In the second picture, they are using (hot) tar to seal the covering used as flashing to the line where the roof meets the walls. Flashing on roofs are a strip of lining used to protect seams around the edges of the roof and any chimneys so water cannot seep into the walls. Flashing is usually a separate strip of some material but here they are using the covering for that purpose.

[roof coverings](https://www.homeadvancement.com/roof/covering/flat-roof)

Comment: Doesn't have to be vinyl or PVC. Mine is fibreglass.

Comment: But @Lambie they are not at all PVC or Vynil while I'm sure these roles are made of "tar".

Comment: Then, they are tar sheets. They are not called black rolls. The tar sheets are usually an underlayment. It's called tar paper felt. **tar felt sheets or rolls***

Comment: Flashing Cement: a trowelable mixture of cutback bitumen and mineral stabilizers, including asbestos or other inorganic fibers. He is using the tar felt as flashing. http://www.shearoofinginc.com/glossary.html